# Which are the minimum values of $m$ and $n$ over integers such that $\frac{n!(n+m)!}{(n-2)!(n+m-2)!} = 2$

Tags: combinatorics

Which are the minimum values of $m$ and $n$ over integers such that $\frac{n!(n+m)!}{(n-2)!(n+m-2)!} = 2$

I am searching for $m$ and $n$ even number's.

Probably there is some software to do this, but I don't know.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: An odd question, the "top" is naturally quite a bit bigger than the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n=2$,$m=0$ seems like the first pair to try:

$\frac{2!2!}{(2-2)!(2+0-2)!}=\frac{2!2!}{0!0!}=\frac{2*2}{1*1}=4$, which is a bit high.

Let's try $n=2$,$m=-2$ then:

$\frac{2!(2-2)!}{(2-2)!(2-2-2)!}=\frac{2!0!}{0!(-2)!}$, so that goes nowhere. **sigh**

Comment: Isn't the numerator $2!2! = 4$?

Comment: Ooops, I corrected my mistakes but didn't find a solution. Thanks @Théophile and Winther

Answer (score 3):

To approach this systematically, let $p = m+n$. We're then looking for $n,p \geq 2$ such that
$$\frac{n!\ p!}{(n-2)!\ (p-2)!} = 2.$$
In other words,
$$n(n-1)p(p-1) = 2.$$
But $n(n-1) \geq 2$ and $p(p-1) \geq 2$, so $n(n-1)p(p-1) \geq 4$, and there are no solutions.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\binom{n}{2}\binom{n+m}{2}=\frac{1}{2}.
$$
The product of two integers has to be an integer.